# Can JSON field names start with a number?

Tags: json, xml, data-conversion

I have this JSON conversion to XML issue I'm trying to figure out and am not sure whether it's a JSON issue or a conversion to XML issue.

```
{
  "AutomaticRenewalFlag" : "false",
  "2ndTierCeid" : "7rfqz",
  "BillingFrequency" : "12"
}
```

Is the second field here valid (`2ndTierCeid`) as far as JSON goes?

I'm getting the following error in the app we're using:

> Failed to transform JSON, error was: java.io.IOException:
> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of elements must consist of
> well-formed character data or markup.

Comment: Sounds like a rather poor JSON to XML converter. There are a lot of them about, and some of them were knocked up in a weekend by people who didn't have a very good understanding of either JSON or XML. From the error message, however there's no obvious link to your use of a name that's invalid in XML, and it might be something completely different.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** *JSON field names may begin with a number; XML element names may **not**.*

---

### Details

**JSON** [has no restrictions unique to the first character](https://www.crockford.com/mckeeman.html) of a `member` `string`,

> ```
> member ::= ws string ws ':' element
>
> string ::= '"' characters '"'
>
> characters ::= "" | character characters
>
> character ::= '0020' . '10FFFF' - '"' - '\' | '\' escape
> ```

but **XML** [does not allow](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-NameStartChar) tag names to begin with a number:

> ```
> Name          ::= NameStartChar (NameChar)*
> NameStartChar ::= ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] |
>                   [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] |
>                   [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] |
>                   [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] |
>                   [#x10000-#xEFFFF]
> NameChar      ::= NameStartChar | "-" | "." | [0-9] | #xB7 |
>                   [#x0300-#x036F] | [#x203F-#x2040]
> ```

---

Therefore, you'll have to restrict your JSON to not begin with a number if you wish there to be an unmodified mapping of JSON keys to XML tag names.